# How to upload category image via REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, swagger

Using swagger I am not seeing any interface out of the box that would allow me to upload category images via API calls, in the same fashion as I can do with product images by base_64 encoding them.

Does anyone have a ready module that would allows me to upload category images? or give point me in the right direction.

Comment: did you tried this one

rest/V1/products/{sku}/media.

Comment: this one will upload product images, I need to upload category images.

Comment: Yes , that was my mistake, I didn't read your question title clearly. Sorry for that.

Comment: no problem, thanks for participation... do you know anything about uploading category images via API?

Comment: No I never did this , and as you mentioned I didn't found any API for the same , if you Found any thing related to this please share.

Comment: hey @Timik, can you please attach or send me a repo for this solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no endpoint to upload category image, I worked on this case before, and i would like to share my solution

first of all, you need to build a custom endpoint to upload the image to this path (send the data in base64 then save it in this path)

> /{magento_root}/pub/media/catalog/category

lets say your image name is **your_image.jpg**

after you save this image in this path, you can send the data using the standard magento endpoint

> /all/V1/categories

```
{
  "category": {
    "parent_id": "2",
    "name": "cat_name",
    "is_active": true,
    "include_in_menu": true,
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "image",
        "value": "your_image.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I will need to implement it and if it works, I will give you the reps. :)

Comment: of course :), and if you need any help please let me know, the most important point for me is helping more than getting the reps.

Comment: Actually since you worked on it before, do you have the module itself? It would be super helpful if you could just post it here.

Comment: unfortunately, this was for a project not separated module , But i can give you what i did. i created new endpoint to save the category file, I sent the content of the image encoded  (base64) , I decoded the content and save them in the catalog/category path with specific name (you have to insure that the name should be unique), after that i i used the standard endpoint does that make sense ?

Comment: It may take awhile until I get to this task, so awarding you with the right answer and the bounty, congrats!

Comment: hey @WISAMHAKIM , can you please attach or send me the code for this solution?